# Enzyme cannot find class

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

That is the component `<Foo />` I want to test

```
...

return (
            <span
                className={`foo ${a === 'b' ? 'bar' : ''} ${className}`}>

                {kitten === 'cats' ?

                    <Cat
                        ... />
                    :

                    <Dog
                       ... />
                }

                <div
                    className={
                        `find-me 
                    ${foo === 'bar' ? 'abc' : 'def'} 
                    ${cats}
                    ${dogs}`
                    }>

                    {
                        children.map((obj, index) => {
                            ...
                        }
               </div>
           </span>
...
```

and thats how I try to test

```
it('constructs correctly when there are three children rendered', () => {
    const component = mount(
        <Foo >
            {options}
        </Foo>
    );

    expect(component.find('.find-me').children()).to.have.lengthOf(3);

    component.unmount();
});
```

But I get

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'have' of undefined

Why cant it find the class?

Comment: `.toHaveLength()`

Comment: @MattCarlotta where can I red about that `to.have.foo`? The docs https://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/ReactWrapper/children.html say `to.have.lengthOf`

Comment: https://jestjs.io/docs/en/expect#tohavelengthnumber

Comment: unfortunately it is not highlighted in enzyme's docs. they provide examples based on [`chai`](https://www.chaijs.com/) system. you are not forced using that since jest provides you with its [own matchers](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/expect)